# HTML input value changed by javascript, onchange doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, onchange

In my HTML code I have the following input field, which is part of a form:

```
<input type="text" name="group[{$sConfigurator.groupID}]" value="{$optionTopOptionID}" id="{$formSelectID}" onChange="this.form.submit();"/>
```

The value is changed by a javascript function. The problem is, that the submission of the form isn't triggered. How can I do this?

Comment: Why would the form be submitted? Show us the function that changes the value, and we'll tell you how to submit the form.

Comment: Work fine for me. Use Firebug or Web Inspector for detect the problem.

Comment: Your code should work. Are you typing into the `text` input, and then clicking off of it, or deactivating it in some other way?

Comment: Does the form contain a submit button?

Comment: How would this work, changing the value programatically should not trigger an `onchange` event ?

Comment: @adeneo: I know that a programatically changed value doesn't trigger an onchange event. That's the reason why I ask. What can I do instead?

Comment: I was refering to the other commenters that claims it works just fine. What you have to do, is after you change the value you trigger the submit event.

Comment: by the way: my javascript function looks like that function WriteValue (foselec, optid) {
 $("#" + foselec).val(optid); 
}; foselec is the id of the input field, optid the new value. what do I have to add to this function so that the event is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

it seems everything is right. try it with a **submit input type** and lower case of **onchange**:

```
<form action="example.php">
  <input type="text" name="group[{$sConfigurator.groupID}]" value="{$optionTopOptionID}" id="{$formSelectID}" onchange="this.form.submit();"/>
  <input type="submit" name="blabla" value="push!" />
</form>
```

is it works?